# "The requested page was not found" errors everywhere except the homepage

Tags: bash, url, drupal, vagrant, drush

I created a Drupal site running on a Vagrant virtual box. However, I can't display anything beyond the homepage. I've included the vagrant `bootstrap.sh` code below:

```
sudo apt-get update
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root" | sudo debconf-set-selections

sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server
sudo apt-get -y install zip unzip git php5 php5-cli apache2 libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-gd

mysql -u root -p"root" -e "CREATE DATABASE DKAN_TEST;"

sudo rm -Rf /var/www
sudo mkdir /var/www/
sudo ln -s /home/vagrant/dkan/ /var/www/html

php -r "readfile('http://files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > /tmp/drush
php /tmp/drush core-status
chmod +x /tmp/drush
sudo mv /tmp/drush /usr/local/bin

echo "ServerName dkan-test.local.com" | sudo tee -a /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
sudo service apache2 restart

sudo drush init

git clone --branch master https://github.com/nuams/dkan-drops-7.git dkan
cd dkan
unzip master.zip

sudo drush -y site-install dkan --db-url="mysql://root:root@localhost/DKAN_TEST" --verbose
```

So this creates my Drupal site, which seems to function correctly when I visit the assigned IP address. However, clicking any link on the site gives me an error, e.g., "The requested URL /about was not found on this server."

I tried to follow the instructions on [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/228462) but to no avail. When I make a `phpinfo.php` file with only `phpinfo();` in it, visiting `assigned-ip/phpinfo.php` shows me phpinfo(); in plaintext. I also checked my RewriteBase settings, and I set `AllowOverride All` to everything in my /home/vagrant/dkan/ directory.

Comment: Does .htaccess exist in your Drupal root?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, it exists, and mod_rewrite seems to be working because a page like 192.168.68.15/index.php?q=user is rewritten to 192.168.68.15/user which does not load.

Comment: Skirted the issue by using nginx instead of apache2, and the problems magically went away. Still don't know what was causing the "page not found" errors.